# Python one liner to substitute a list indices

Tags: python

I want to replace those elements of `list1` whose indices are stored in list `indices` by `list2` elements. Following is the current code:

```
j=0
for idx in indices:
   list1[idx] = list2[j]
   j+=1
```

Is it possible to write a one-liner for the above four lines using **lambda function** or **list comprehension**?

**EDIT**
`list1` contains float values
`list2` contains float values
`indices` contain integers between `0` and `len(list1)`

Comment: No, list comprehensions can't modify existing lists.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `list1`, `list2` and `incides` would contain?

Comment: @MorganThrapp The option of creating a new list is *open*!

Comment: @MorganThrapp It's bad practice, but they can: `x = [0, 0, 0];  [x.__setitem__(i, 5) for i in range(3)]; print(x)` would print `[5, 5, 5]`.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 I mean, yes, you can do that. If you do that in production code though, I will hurt you.

Comment: for j, idx in enumerate(indices): list1[idx] = list2[j]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions),

```
# A test case
list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = ['c', 'e', 'a']
indices = [2, 4, 0]

# Use conditional expressions
new_list = [list2[indices.index(idx)] if idx in indices else v for idx, v in enumerate(list1)] # idx2 = indices.index(idx), for list2

print(new_list)
# Output
['a', 1, 'c', 3, 'e', 5, 6]
```

Comment: Hi, this one doesn't seem right. Why select `idx` entry of `list2`? `list1[idx]` entry is to be replaced with `list2` entries (in a serial way).

Comment: @vvy, thx, I edited my answer with an example. The result is consistent with your original code.

Answer (score 3):

Although it is not a one liner, here is an alternative that I think is more readable:

```
for i, v in zip(indices, list2):
    list1[i] = v
```

Comment: and of course if you move `list1[i] = v` onto the same line as the `for` loop it would then be 1 line, this is definitely the cleanest answer!

Answer (score 2):

It's not so pretty but you could solve it like this :

```
map(list1.__setitem__, indices, list2)
```

Comment: Though clever, PEP 20 may object.

Comment: I agree with you guys but OP asked for a "one liner", I delivered it :)